# How to calculate blank space

Tags: c

i have been trying calculate the amount of blank space in a sentence, but I don't know how to let the program know which sentence that I want it to calculate, please help me, here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int wid, len, i, j, temp, blank;
char text[100], ch;

int main(){
printf ("Enter the width of the colum: ");
gets (text);
sscanf (text, "%d", &wid);
printf ("\nEnter a line of text: ");
gets (text);

len = strlen (text);
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    printf ("1234567890");
}
while(len > 50){
    printf ("\nThe text is too long!\n");
    break;
}
ch = getch();
for (j = 0; j < len; j++){
    if (ch == ' ') {blank++;}
}
printf ("\n%d", blank);
}
```

I want to calculate how many blank for this part
    printf ("\nEnter a line of text: ");
    gets (text);

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, what does it do? What should it do instead?

Comment: Are you sure you want **blank_space_in_a_sentence** or do you want **blank_space_in_a_line**? That matters. Line is easier, as sentences generally break across multiple lines. Do you also have a set of punctuation you consider **end_of_sentence_punctuation?** Like `., ?, !, and/or ;`?

Comment: Since it has not been said yet here: never ever use `gets`. Instead use for example `fgets`, in this case `fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin);` (note, `sizeof` will only work when `text` is array and not pointer, if it is pointer then you need to know the size by some other mechanism, like hard-coding value 100 in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
ch = getch();
for (j = 0; j < len; j++){
if (ch == ' ') {blank++;}
```

try

```
for(j = 0; j < len; j++)
{
    if(text[j] == ' ') //comparing if the string in text contains blank space at position j
        blank++;
}
```

also, instead of gets() to read the string, use fgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* cprogram to count blanck spaces in the string*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int len,i,blank_space=0;
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter the string ");
    fgets(str,20,stdin);
    printf("%s",str);
    //claculate string length 
    len=strlen(str);
    //printing length of the string
    printf("length of the string is %d",len);
    //loop to detect blankspaces
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
        blank_space++;
    }
    //display the result
    printf("no of blanked spaces is %d",blank_space);
    return 0;
```

}